# регулярные выражения (php) и перенос строк

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

здравствуйте, есть две такие регулярки: `'~\*\*([^*]+)\*\*~'` и `~""(.+?)""~`, но они не улавливают текст если в нём есть табы, переносы и тд. как можно это исправить? spasibo

Comment: Первая регулярка должна отрабатывать нормально. А так, используйте модификатор **s**.

Answer (score 0):

Первое выражение работает корректно: https://regex101.com/r/ewCJD2/1

Второе будет работать корректно при условии добавления в конец модификатора s (`~""(.+?)""~s`): https://regex101.com/r/G8ESRY/1